# Eclipse Progress View is not refreshing when running many jobs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I've problem with running big number of concurrent *Jobs* in my *Eclipse RCP* application. When I start 100 *Jobs* (like the one bellow), they execute normally but after they are finished they are still visible in *Progress View* for about 10 seconds. I would like *Progress View* to clear *Jobs* immediately after they are finished. If I start less *Jobs* (eg. 10) *Progress View* refreshes it self immediately.

```java
class MyJob extends Job
{
    public MyJob(String name) {
        super(name);
    } 

    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor){
            //SOME EXPENSIVE COMPUTATIONS
        BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger("0");
        for ( int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++ ) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bigint = bigint.add(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        monitor.done();

        System.out.println(new Random().nextInt());
        return new  Status(IStatus.OK, "foo", "OK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

each job is scheduled as a separate thread and in case there are lots of them  locking/synchronization/thread management mechanisms take some overhead. for [example some internal Eclipse Jobs code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.core/org.eclipse.core.jobs/3.5.0.v20100515/org/eclipse/core/internal/jobs/InternalWorker.java#37) explicitly puts progress-bar-feedback mechanism into sleep for 250ms. such solutions probably pile up into long delays.

anyway having 100 entries in Progress View is not user firendly. I'd suggest grouping those jobs with `Job.setProgressGroup()`. perhaps having less entries in the view will cover up slow responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I'd say it's better to allocate your own Threads than to use Jobs.  Your 100 Jobs are going to start using the Job Threads that would be used to do Workbench maintenance.  Allocating your own Threads means the Jobs Thread pool doesn't grow to the max value and stay there.

I'd have one Job that starts your Threads and reports progress to the Progress View.  You could use SubMonitor to split the main IProgressMonitor into 100 so each of the Thread/Runnable pairs you start can report progress back to the main Job.